# How can I get src tag inside a tag inside innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

dev tools -> console ->

```
var x= document.getElementsByClassName('ad-area')[0].innerHTML;

x returns:
'<a href="/members/spotlight/311"><img class="block-banner" src="https://test.gif"></a>'
```

how can I get src? https://test.gif

so something like...

```
var v = document.getElementById("x").src;
```

any help please? TY

Comment: `x.split('src=');` should get you pretty close to what you want. I'm sure you can find code out there to get it exactly.

Comment: Why not `document.querySeletcor('.ad-area img').src`  ? Why do you need innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to chain a selector to grab items by TagName and then read the attribute of src.

```js
const imageSource = document
  .getElementsByClassName('ad-area')[0]
  .getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
  .getAttribute("src");
console.warn("imageSource: ", imageSource); // imageSource:  https://test.gif
```

```html
<div class="ad-area">
  <a href=""><img src="https://test.gif"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. I mean `getAttribute("src")` - seriously? Also, ever heard of `querySelector`?

Comment: @Spectric Actually, I can see the use case for `getAttribute("src")` over `.src` as it gets the "raw" attribute value. `.src` will resolve relative paths.

Comment: @JonP which means `.src` is usually more useful

Comment: @Spectric, true in most cases, unless you want the value as set. As the original question was regarding extracting from inner html, that *may* be the case here. Personally I'd use `.src` 99% of the time.

Comment: @Spectric I was trying to build off of what he had in hopes that it might be more understandable but you're welcome to post another answer with an alternative solution.